# The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProjectName'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Without any reason, an error appeared in my views today :

> CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Website' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And the error is underlined at this line in my view :

```
@model Website.Models.EventIntro // Models is in red
```

I can't find the problem behind that error, any help would be welcome!

**My Environment:**
VS 2017 , MVC 5.2.3.0

**What i have tried so far :**

-Switching to 3.0.0.0 in `<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />`

-Cleaning ASP.NET temp files

EDIT: my model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class EventIntro
    {
        public EventIntro() { }
        public HtmlString Heading { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Intro { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Body { get; set; }
        public HtmlString EventImage { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Highlights { get; set; }
        public HtmlString StartDate { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Duration { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Difficulty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your model code

Comment: Is the namespace correct in the `EventIntro` declaration? It may be worth posting that class. Also check that you are not referencing or have declared another namespace along the lines of `xxx.Website.xxx` or similar. Check the namespace global references in `Views\Web.config`. Also there may be another build error in the assembly causing that class not to be found. If `EventInfo` is in another project check you have changed that to a higher version of the .Net framework than that of the website project.

Comment: @Tom John. I checked everything you said and all seems OK.
I posted the model code just in case it helps

Comment: @ArnaudAd I suspect you have some other reference or class declared in a similar namespace that is confusing the view. Try explicitly including the namespace in the `Views\Web.config` and changing the model declaration to `@model EventIntro`

Comment: I just added <add namespace="Website.Models" /> in my web.config and updated in my view : @model EventIntro and it still does not work :(

Comment: @ArnaudAd try changing the namespace in that class to something completely random and see if can then be referenced.